# Setting up ssh keys to connect to gitlab

Tags: windows-10, ssh, git, gitlab, rsa

*Note: Using windows 10 (I know, I know... that's what they gave me :/)

Hi all,

I'm new to using GitLab, but my company has their own GitLab server where I'm to house repos for my projects, push commits, etc. I'm trying to set up my ssh key pair, but I'm getting stuck and not really sure what to do. I followed the instructions on the gitlab site for setting up ssh key pairs. I now have a folder `C:/Users/{username}/.ssh` containing the files `id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub`, and `known_hosts`.

I read about needing a config file, and based on what I've pieced together through searches, I just wrote one up in NotePad with the contents

```
# GitLab.com
Host git.{mycompany}.org
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# Private GitLab instance
Host git.{mycompany}.org
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I am unable to connect to the server, however, despite having added my key to my GitLab account.

On running `ssh -Tvvv git@git.{mycompany}.org`, the output is:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\{user}/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\{user}/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for git.{mycompany}.org
debug1: C:\\Users\\{user}/.ssh/config line 7: Applying options for git.{mycompany}.org
debug2: add_identity_file: ignoring duplicate key ~/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "git.{mycompany}.org" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to git.{mycompany}.org {ip.address.masked} port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\{user}/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\{user}/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

(Obviously, stuff in brackets was edited for privacy).

I'm sorry for the general and I'm sure basic question, but I'm at a bit of a loss here and really want to just get this working so I can stop manually uploading commits via web browser ><

Comment: This _could_ be (1) an error in or rejection by the remote ssh server, in which case you need to look at the server logs and config if you have access, or else talk to someone who does (2) a problem elsewhere in the network connecting you to the server, such as a firewall or IPS or even a router 'too clever for its britches', in which case you need someone (sometimes several people) who know about that network, although a wire-level trace (on Windows I recommend Wireshark) may help some. One thing it definitely is _not_ is your key.

Comment: Ah, okay, I'll have to submit a ticket then. But my config file looks fine? I was really just shooting in the dark there, so I was really expecting that to be the issue

Comment: Having two duplicate entries in the config is redundant and a bit silly, but not harmful. Specifying ~/.ssh/id_rsa is unnecessary because it's in the default, but not harmful. 'Fine' is somewhat subjective, but the config is not causing your problem.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. The examples I saw on the GitLab site had a config with two Hosts, one for GitLab.com and one for the other server, so (not knowing much about how this stuff works) I blindly copy/pasted and replaced the hosts and left it at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

This basically means that the remote server is closing the SSH connection immediately after accepting it.

The simplest explanation is that the remote server is configured not to accept SSH connections from your IP address for some reason. Some systems use [TCP Wrappers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Wrappers) to control this. The OpenSSH server also has its own directives which can be added to its `sshd_config` file.

If you're an administrator of the remote server, check the sshd logs (probably in the `/var/logs` directory) to see if it's logging a reason for dropping the connection. If you're not an administrator, contact the administrators for help.

Comment: Thank you! I am indeed *not* an admin of the server -- not even of my own laptop... infuriating when I need to submit an IT request just to run `pip install {whateverpackage}` >:( I'll submit a request to have them sort it out, though. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

While I marked Kenster's answer correct (as he was), in case anyone else runs into a similar problem, I found out from IT that our gitlab server has SSH disabled -- the 'connection' I see happening is an artifact of the Zscaler private access system the company uses. SSH makes a TCP connection through the private access firewall, but then gets dropped immediately since it's not a 'real' service that's enabled. Cheers!